# Silverlight MediaElement

Tags: silverlight

Am new to Silverlight. Have added the MediaElement and Placed the Media file(.wmv format) with .xap file . ,Media Element is not visible . I want to know how can i Make it Visible on the application run...

Comment: Could you show us the code/xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that a MediaElement is not a Media Player.  At least no in the sense of all the UI goodness of buttons or dials, sliders and the like.  For that you'll need to biuld, burrow or buy the player.

One place to start is with Microsoft Expression Encoder, that ships the complete source for a full featured, skinable player.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to play the media element without all of a media player functionalities (start, stop, next, pause and other buttons plus a progress bar), you can simply set it's property `AutoPlay` to true and it will start as soon as the page is loaded.
If you want some more control over the clip playback, you can call `MediaElement` instance methods like `Play`, `Stop`, `Pause` from your code behind.